# isLoaded for ExtJS data store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**This is not a question but maybe I can help others with that code.**

Because ExtJS store does not have something like isLoaded() I override it.
But it takes me some time to figure it out and get it to work.
Here is the code (in coffee script). Feel free to use it.

By doing that you can do with any store (associations as well):

```
store.isLoaded
```

If you want to call a method on a store but you need the store loaded you can use

```
store.invokeWhenLoaded(yourFunction)
```

Code is self explaining (I think :-))

```
###
Because Ext.data.Store is missing something like 'isLoaded'
this adds the possibility to figure it out.
As a bonus ;-) there is a method called invokeWhenLoaded that you can
pass a function to that will be called once the store is loaded.
###
Ext.data.AbstractStore.override(
  constructor:(config) ->
    # Add additional properties to config
    Ext.apply(config, {
      isLoaded: false
      waitlist: []
    })
    # Call overridden constructor and remember return value
    rslt = @callOverridden(arguments)
    # Add onLoad listener
    @on('load', @onLoad)
    rslt

  # Executes each function in the waitlist and finally clears the waitlist
  processWaitlist:()->
    unless @waitlist.isEmpty()
      fn() for fn in @waitlist
      @waitlist = []

  ###
  Executes fn if the store is loaded or adds it to the waitlist if not.
  The fn will be called as soon the store is loaded
  It will try to load the store as well unless param loadLater is true

  Params:
    fn - the function to call once the store is loaded
  ###
  invokeWhenLoaded:(fn)->
    if @isLoaded 
      fn()
    else
      @waitlist.push(fn)

  ###
  @private event onLoad
  "Fires whenever the store [has read] data from a remote data source."
  ###
  onLoad:()->
    unless @isLoaded
      @isLoaded = true
      @processWaitlist()
)
```

Comment: Good idea. I did almost exactly same thing in my project, except I stored not the `bool` value but time stamp, so I can see when was the last time store was loaded. It's useful if you need to have some kind of auto-refresh mechanism.

Comment: This is a nice idea, we have a situation in a project at the moment when a page load triggers say 5-6 stores to be loaded, but we need to mask the page until all have completed. (or something similar) will certainly return here shortly to see if this kind of thing can be sensibly chained.